# vuejs - good practices when using getters and/or computed properties

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties, vue-reactivity

I love vue.js and I definitely love computed properties and `VueX` getters. But I have come to a point where I am not sure if the way I am using them might have some drawbacks in terms of performance.

This is a common pattern throughout my code (same applies to local components data and computed properties):

From this simple state (source of truth):

```
export default () => ({
   bonds: {
    eth: [],
    celo: []
  }
})
```

I will usually go as follows within my getters:

```
export default {
  getBondsEth(state) {
    return state.bonds.eth
  },
  getBondsCelo(state) {
    return state.bonds.celo
  },
  getTotalBondsEth(_, getters) {
    return getters.getBondsEth.length
  },
  getTotalBondsCelo(_, getters) {
    return getters.getBondsCelo.length
  },
  getTotalBonds(_, getters) {
    return getters.getTotalBondsEth + getters.getTotalBondsCelo
  },
  getWhateverComputationEth(_, getters) {
    return getters.getBondsEth.reduce... or map or filter or find etc....
  }
  ...
}
```

So, my questions will be

1. Will this be considered a bad practice since I am using getters that depends on others? Are these considered circular dependencies?
2. Should I always derived my getters directly from the source of truth? For example, change the above to...

```
getTotalBonds(state) {
    return state.bonds.eth.length + state.bonds.celo.length
}
```

3. Is there a way to debug my getters or computed properties using the browser console so I can make sure I do not have performance issues or weird iteration loops, etc?

And thank you very much if you take the time to answer!

Comment: If this is Vuex question, consider mentioning this, as this is a different case from arbitrary JS getter

Comment: yes, it is a vuex/vue related question! Not related to native JS getters. Sorry for that!

Comment: Then it's what the answer says on computeds. It's a good practice, and you can debug them the same way you'd do with random JS function, i.e. with breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask. Not really a good question from my side

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be a circular dependency. It would be circular dependency in case when getter `A` would depend on getter `B` and getter `B` would depend on getter `A`, which would create an infinite recursion.

Getters are fine, but AFAIK they get called by Vue on every tick (more on what the *tick* is [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#dom-update-timing)), which would be wasteful most of the time. So for rarely changing values the use `computed` is encouraged, since `computed` gets called only once and Vue caches the result of execution.

Comment: It looks like the question addresses Vuex getters that are efficiently Vue computeds, although this is not explicitly stated

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the circular dependency concept! I've realised that my question was not properly stated here and ended up solving it through vuejs discord.